# Alternative to Authorize.net Direct Post?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, authorize.net

Magento2 - payment method Authorize.net developer support notes that [Direct Post Method is deprecated](https://developer.authorize.net/api/upgrade_guide/#dpm) which is replaced with `Accept.js`.

> Are there any plans for Magento 2 Community Edition to integrate with
>   Authorize.net in this way?

Comment: Magento 2.3.1 version supports Authorize.net AcceptJs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.1OpenSource.html and